# How can i execute two javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in HTML, PHP. I have build a page with following coding -

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/timepicki.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timepicki.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$(".time_element").timepicki();
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryCalendar.css">
<script>

   jQuery(function () {
      jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      jQuery( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
 </script>
```

problem is only second one is working. If I put the first portion in the place of second it also work but both together does not. How can I combine those. I tried "body onload" method and also tried "addloadevent" but probably I am not writing the code properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't include jQuery more than once. And **do** include a vaguely-recent version (1.6 is not vaguely recent).

Answer (score 1):

You're including jQuery more than once. Don't do that. Just include it once, then include your plugins. You can leave your `ready` blocks separate, or combine them, it's up to you.

Here's how I would change that:

In the `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timepicki.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryCalendar.css">
```

In the `body` at the very end prior to the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/timepicki.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".time_element").timepicki();
$("#datepicker, #datepicker1" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

...where `jquery.min.js` is a recent version of jQuery, such as v1.11.2.

Or if you want all the scripts in the `head` (although that's usually not best practice):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timepicki.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryCalendar.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/timepicki.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".time_element").timepicki();
  $("#datepicker, #datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Other changes I'd probably make:

- Give `#datepicker` and `#datepicker1` a common class rather than `id`s (as with your `.time_element`).
- Combine the CSS into a single, minified file.
- Combine the JS into a single, minified file (or possibly all the JS except for jQuery, and load jQuery from a CDN).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your code is OK but I think the JS I used having some issue. That is why still only one (either date or time) work at a time. However after changed with a new script it is working fine. Thanks once again.